# Polymer iron page and z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have this structure

```
 <paper-header-panel class="flex" mode="waterfall-tall" main>
        <paper-toolbar class="tall header-toolbar">
             <neon-animated-pages>
                 <login-button></login-button>
                 <login-window></login-window>
             </neon-animated-pages> 
        </paper-toolbar>
        <neon-animated-pages>
           <home-page></home-page>
           <blog-page></blog-page>
        </neon-animated-pages>
 </paper-header-panel>
```

I use ripple animation for transition from login-button to login-window. Login window is fullscreen fixed element. But when i use element with z-index > 0 in home-page or blog-page, this element overrides login-window.
How can i fix it?